# Android Phone_State not getting incoming calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

The problem in my work is if I give the `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` intent from the shell it works but does not get the phone number. But the main problem is that when I call my phone it does not get any effect. What is the problem when I call my phone with another phone when the app is closed, why not receive this call?

**Here is AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="homework.contactor">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Here is the Receiver Code:**

```
package homework.contactor;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public static Boolean phoneRinging = false;

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
                phoneRinging = false;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
                phoneRinging = false;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
                phoneRinging = true;

                break;
        }
    }
}

public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    TelephonyManager telephony;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        telephony.listen(null, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code, it is working for me

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ramesh. This is works for me now. But the number not be shown yet.

Comment: check Permissions, if your using Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Comment: Why is the listener created inside a broadcast receiver?